# Vue.js - proxy in vue.config.js is being ignored

Tags: vue.js, proxy

I have been searching and reading thru documentation on this topic but I was unbale to make it work.
https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#devserver-proxy

I made my Vue.js application normaly by the commnand

```
vue create my-app
```

so I'm running the app by command

```
npm run serve
```

on http://localhost:8080/. Pretty standart stuff.

But my app needs a PHP backend which is running at https://localhost/
So I setted up the proxy setting in vue.confic.js file in my root directory.

Content of vue.confic.js file:

```
module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        proxy: {
            '^/api': {
                target: 'https://localhost/',
                ws: true,
                changeOrigin: true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

And I'm trying to make axios call for the script on the adress

```
https://localhost/test.php
```

The axios call is

```
mounted() {
    this.$axios.get('api/test.php', {})
        .then(response => { console.log(response.data) })
        .catch(error => { console.log(error) });
    },
```

But for some reason which i cant figure out I'm still getting

```
GET http://localhost:8080/api/test.php 404 (Not Found)
```

Thank you in advance. I'll be happy for any tips.

Comment: What port is the api running on?

Answer (score 0):

Your axios call is going to make the request to the API with whatever protocol the webpage is on.

The error shows that you’re making an http call but your webpack config is only spoofing https. Are you visiting https from the page making the request?

Eg https://localhost:8080

You can also try updating your webpack proxy server to look like this

```js
module.exports = {
  //...
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'https://other-server.example.com',
        secure: false
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Additional debug steps: curl your Api endpoint from your terminal to see if it’s a protocol issue

Answer (score -1):

you can try

https: true,

```
proxy: {
            '/api': {
                target: 'https://localhost/',
                ws: true,
                changeOrigin: true
            }
        }
```

before try, restart by `npm run serve` to make it sense