# Vue vue.config.js proxy 404

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am following the tutorial from [Vue JS 2 Tutorial #32 - HTTP Requests](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=btDfVBPYI-U) with vue-resource to `jsonplaceholder.typicode.com`. If I don't proxy it, it'll give out CORS error.

vue.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      '^/api': {
        target: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com',
        ws: true,
        changeOrigin: true,
        pathRewrite: { '^/api': '' }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

HTTP post request:

```
this.$http.post('/api/posts', {
    userId: 1,
    title: this.blog.title,
    body: this.blog.content,
}).then(function (data) {
  console.log(data)
});
```

Error:

```
XHR POST http://localhost:8080/api/posts [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 3ms]
```

I have tried:

- [Vue.js - proxy in vue.config.js is being ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58580280/vue-js-proxy-in-vue-config-js-is-being-ignored)
- https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#devserver-proxy
- [Vue proxy setting does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50912749/vue-proxy-setting-does-not-work)
- with axios, and with vue-resource

Edits:

- Changed `'/api/post'` to `'/api/posts'`, still not working.
- Tried changing `'/api/posts'` to  `'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'` which resulted in CORS error.
- Added `pathRewrite: { '^/api': '' }` into vue.config.json proxy, still not working.
- Tried [Proxy changeOrigin setting doesn't seem to work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58752889/14108351), still not working.

Comment: i think the URL should be `/api/posts`

Answer (score 0):

I see your request if going to your localhost instead of the actual server that you want to hit, have you tried changing `this.$http.post('/api/post', {` to `this.$http.post('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/api/post', {`

For what I can see on vuecli's documentation the fact that you proxy the server doesn't mean that you need to stop writing the URL of that server on your requests.

Comment: Yes, I have. Which cause CORS Error.

Answer (score 0):

Try restart your dev server. A full restart is required to apply the changes.